# Unable to Play Recorded Android Audio File

Tags: javascript, android, audio, react-native

I have implemented the library react-native-audio-recorder-player, and am able to record audio. However, whenever I try to play the audio from the recorded path I receive an error. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? This seems to be a fairly common library but there isn't much information available. Additionally, I have already asked and been granted all the permissions to record audio and read/write to external storage.
Here is my code that records the audio then plays the audio respectively, the functions are triggered onPress of custom buttons.

```
onStartRecord = async () => {
const path = Platform.select({
  ios: 'hello.m4a',
  android: 'sdcard/hello.mp4',
});
console.log(path);
//Result is the URL of the file
const result = await audioRecorderPlayer.startRecorder(path);
audioRecorderPlayer.addRecordBackListener((e) => {
  console.log(e);
  this.setState({
    recordSecs: e.current_position,
    recordTime: audioRecorderPlayer.mmssss(Math.floor(e.current_position)),
  });
  return;
});
console.log(`Result: ${result}`);
};

onStartPlay = async () => {
console.log('onStartPlay');
const path = Platform.select({
  ios: 'hello.m4a',
  android: 'sdcard/hello.mp4',
});
console.log(path);
const msg = await this.audioRecorderPlayer.startPlayer(path);
console.log(msg);
this.audioRecorderPlayer.addPlayBackListener((e) => {
  if (e.current_position === e.duration) {
    console.log('finished');
    this.audioRecorderPlayer.stopPlayer();
  }
  this.setState({
    currentPositionSec: e.current_position,
    currentDurationSec: e.duration,
    playTime: this.audioRecorderPlayer.mmssss(
      Math.floor(e.current_position),
    ),
    duration: this.audioRecorderPlayer.mmssss(Math.floor(e.duration)),
  });
  return;
});
};
```

After running the audio onStartPlay() here is the error I receive:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.audioRecorderPlayer.startPlayer')
> _callee3$@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:99040:76
> tryCatch@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:24976:23
> invoke@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25149:32
> tryCatch@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:24976:23
> invoke@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25049:30
> http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25079:19
> tryCallTwo@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:27040:9
> doResolve@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:27204:25
> Promise@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:27063:14
> callInvokeWithMethodAndArg@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25078:33
> enqueue@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25083:157
> async@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25100:69
> _callee3@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:99032:42
> onPress@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:99154:31
> _performTransitionSideEffects@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:55035:22
> _receiveSignal@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:54977:45
> onResponderRelease@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:54886:34
> invokeGuardedCallbackImpl@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:9186:21
> invokeGuardedCallback@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:9280:42
> invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:9284:36
> executeDispatch@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:9356:48
> executeDispatchesInOrder@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:9376:26
> executeDispatchesAndRelease@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:10451:35
> forEach@[native code]
> forEachAccumulated@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:9518:22
> runEventsInBatch@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:10475:27
> runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:10554:25
> http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:10530:42
> batchedUpdates$1@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:21179:20
> batchedUpdates@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:10437:36
> _receiveRootNodeIDEvent@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:10529:23
> receiveTouches@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:10582:34
> __callFunction@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2765:36
> http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2497:31
> __guard@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2719:15
> callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2496:21
> callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]